# How to use AFWall+ to forward packets through a wireguard VPN to a tethered device?

Tags: vpn, android, port-forwarding, iproute, wireguard

situation is pretty simple, but I've spending the last 3 days trying to find a solution to this with no luck.

I have a printer at home that I need to have access to from my laptop. The printer is in a remote garage with no wifi connectivity what so ever - so I decided to use an old Android phone I had as a hotspot (through LTE\5G). The Android phone and my laptop are connected to the same wireguard VPN - `10.6.0.0/24`.

I managed to share the VPN connection with the printer - and when pinging my laptop from the printer - it works just fine (because the phone, which is the gateway, knows how to reach my laptop through the VPN) - but sadly, the other way around doesn't work and I can't access the printer web interface, running on port `9000`, which is my goal here.

I was thinking I need to somehow route all traffic coming to the phone on port, let's say, `9001`, to the printer IP address on port `9000`.

```
laptop wireguard IP is 10.6.0.3

phone wireguard IP is 10.6.0.4

printer IP which it received from the phone is 192.168.146.200
```

After more research I discovered the app `AFWall+` which seems to allow me to create custom routing rules, but that's where I got stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If I understand, it's about making an Android application behave differently than offered: route/forward incoming access from remote through VPN, rather than only route outgoing access from local (printer) through VPN. Unless you have complete control with shell over the firewall rules made on Android and the WireGuard low level settings applied, this question should be asked on [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) . Also please check comments asking you for more information in your questions and be sure you address them.

Comment: I apologize, I went back to the printer and logged the dmesg output before and after using usb_modeswitch like you asked, but wasn't sure how to link such a big log in a comment